# Regex: Not matching a list of words

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking to apply a regular expression to an input string to make sure it doesn’t match a list of predefined values. For example, if I pass in the word Dog, I don’t want it to match. Likewise for Cat. However, if I pass in Sheep, it should match. 
I’ve tried:

```
^(?!(Dog)|(Cat))$ << Doesn’t match Dog, Cat or sheep!
^((?!Dog)|(?!Cat))$ << Doesn’t match Dog, Cat or sheep!
^(?!Dog|Cat)$ << Doesn’t match Dog, Cat or sheep!
^(?!Dog)|(?!Cat)$ << matches everything because Dog != Cat for example
```

Basically, if I pass in "Dogs", it should match as dog != dogs. But if I pass in exactly dog or cat then it should not match.

I thought this would be really easy, but I'm puling my hair out!
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The lookahead assertions doesn't match anything. after closing it you need to match the characters, so try e.g.

```
^(?!.*Dog)(?!.*cat).*$
```

See it [here at Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tums)

They are described [here in detail on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx)

If you want to match those words exactly then use word boundaries like this

```
^(?!.*\bDog\b)(?!.*\bCat\b).*$
```

[Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tunb)

The `\b` ensures that there is no word character before or following

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (albeit bravely) that I've understood the question, I believe that the issue here is in the use zero width expressions, and the case sensitivity of the strings you are looking to search for.

I think that what you need is listed below.

```
void Main()
{
    string test = "sheep";

    var regEx = new Regex("^([dD][oO][gG]|[cC][aA][tT])$");

    Console.WriteLine(regEx.IsMatch(test) ? "Found" : "Not Found");
}
```

Alternatively, you could do this without regex as follows

```
void Main()
{
    List<string> excludeStrings = new List<string> { "dog", "cat" };

    string inputString = "Dog";

    Console.WriteLine(excludeStrings.Contains(inputString, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? "Found" : "Not Found");
}
```

Comment: There is a great thing called "ignoreCase" modifier see [here on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04xx80ds.aspx), that makes regex case insensitive